# what does the function returns with in C program , in case if there is no return statement in the code

Tags: c, return, return-value

I made a function on how to reverse a singly linked list recursively in C.

the function is as below.

```
struct node * reverseSLL2(struct node *p,struct node *temp)
{
    struct node *temp1;
    if(p!=NULL)
    {
        temp1=p->link;
        p->link=temp;
        reverseSLL2(temp1,p);
        //return;
    }
    else
    {
        return temp;
    }    



}
```

I call head=reverseSLL2(head,NULL) , where head is the pointer to the first node of my linked list.The program works correctly!

But , I have two question here :

1) My all the call to the function except the last call , do not reach to the return statement , then what does those functions returns with ?

2) If I write(uncomment) the return statement that has been commented in the previous code. In that case what does the function returns with ?

Thank you.

Comment: If there is no return statement then it will lead to UB.

Comment: @al-Acme It has been a long time since I programmed in C, but I seem to remember Undefined Behavior only occurs if the execution goes along the branch which has no return statement. In the OP's code, if the `if` condition always evaluates false, there is no UB. Is this correct?

Comment: @Happy - read `dasblinkenlight`'s answer.

Comment: If you uncomment the `return` statement the code will no longer compile.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight : it do compile and work correctly. in gcc

Comment: @munjal007: `gcc` compiles as GNU C 89 (a mostly compatible C89-dialect) by default. In C89, `return` without an expression in a non-`void` function is equivalent to reaching the `}` that terminates the function definition. In C99, this has been removed, and with `-std=c99 -pedantic`, you get at a warning.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is undefined behavior. Compiling the code should produce a warning about reaching the end of a function through a code path that is missing a `return`.

The reason you do not see that the function is broken, and observe it producing the right results, is because the actual value that is returned from the base case branch (i.e. the `else`) does have a correct `return`. It is possible that the compiled code reuses that last return value in all invocations of the function up the stack, so the caller ends up getting the intended value.

However, the code is invalid. You should add `return` in front of the recursive call to fix the problem:

```
return reverseSLL2(temp1,p);
```

Comment: Sir, if the return statement is missing and value of the function call is used by the caller, it is a perfect UB. but what if the return value is not used by the caller? I'm referring to 6.9.1, paragraph 12, c99. What am i missing?

Comment: @SouravGhosh Nothing. All current answers are incorrect in this regard. (Quoth the standard: "If the } that terminates a function is reached, **and the value of the function call is used by the caller**, the behavior is undefined.")

Comment: @SouravGhosh I assume that your question is theoretical, because if one does not use the return value of `reverseSLL2` then the whole list except the first node would be lost. If you do not use the return value of a function that lacks `return` statement, there would be no UB. I assume that this is a "leftover" from the pre-ANSI days when there was no `void` type, and `int` was implicitly used in its place.

Comment: @Wintermute OP is definitely using the return value of the function: "I call `head=reverseSLL2(head,NULL)`..."

Comment: Yes, absolutely theoretical. I just wanted to clear up my doubt for the case of non-usage of the return value. Thanks.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight sir, It is UB , but  then how I able to get the head pointer pointed to the last node , as I coded ?

Comment: @munjal007 That is what I was trying to explain in the second paragraph. Your function gets called several times - first, from the code that you use for testing; then recursively. The last invocation has `return temp`, so it loads the pointer to last node into the location used for returning values. Invocations that go after do not have `return`, and they happen to not harm the location where the return value is stored. That's how `temp` from the last invocation makes it all the way to the original caller.

Comment: @munjal007 The part where prior invocations do not harm the location used for return values is crucial: this happens to be true for this one compiler that you used, but other compilers may use a different strategy for returning values, which would lead to the value of `temp` being destroyed in the process of unwinding the chain of recursive invocations.

Answer (score 3):

When a non-void function returns without a return statement, it  is **Undefined Behaviour** (UB). Make sure to avoid this.

However, the function still might return something even without using the return statement. For example, on x86 architectures, the function will return whatever is there in the `eax` register, which will most probably be one of the local variables.

Answer (score 1):

I'll bet you're running on a machine where the function result is in a register (EAX on 32-bit x86 for example), and the return value from the recursive call is still sitting in that register when you return without a value by falling off the end of the function.  The compiler doesn't have to use that sequence, so it's still Undefined Behavior.

You can fix your version by simply adding the return to the recursive call:

```
return reverseSLL2(temp1,p);
```